# API Python, many pages as parameters

Tags: python, api

Good afternoon people,

I have an API that I want to consume, but it has more than one page to fetch information.

In the example below, I'm searching on page 1, but I have 50+ pages to query. How to customize this to automatically fetch all pages?

Then I will save in a variable to configure a dataframe

---

import json,requests

link = "https://some.com.br/api/v1/integration/customers.json"

headers = {'iliot-company-token': '3r5s$ddfdassss'}

Parameters = {"page": 1}

clients2 = requests.get(link, headers=headers, json=Parameters)

lista_clients2 = clients.json

print(lista_clients2())

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have exactly 50 pages, numbered 1-50, this approach might work - defining your request as a function/method then using `map` to got through all pages.  This assumes all of the pages would have the same header, API token etc.

```
import json,requests

link = "https://some.com.br/api/v1/integration/customers.json"

headers = {'iliot-company-token': '3r5s$ddfdassss'}

def get_data(page):    
    Parameters = {"page": page}
    clients2 = requests.get(link, headers=headers, json=Parameters)
    lista_clients2 = clients.json
    print(lista_clients2())

#Get it all at once
all_page_data = list(map(get_data, range(1,51)))


#If you want to make a dataframe
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(all_page_data) 
#You can also split out json-formatted data, if it's in a single column
full_df = pd.json_normalize(df[0])
```

Comment: Tks @AlecZ, Results OK,and  I'd like to break the code because sometimes I don't know how many pages the API has